# PHP Decorator Writer Script

Tags: php, oop, decorator

I am starting to use decorators in PHP more often these days to modify an object's behavior at run-time.  My problem is primarily one of laziness, we have many legacy classes with tons of methods and the thought of having to re-write/override all of them for each decorator class makes me sad.  Does anyone know of a command line utility that exists that would write these decorators for me?

Or maybe there's a better way to go about this?

Comment: That many decorators may be a design flaw, but I'll leave it be as a legacy thing. I'm not aware of any cli utility, but using a `ReflectionClass` pretty much can give you all the data you need, leaving you to simply loop through the properties and output PHP in simple string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question I understand you are too lazy to add the *other* methods, e.g. those that do not modify the decorated instance. For this purpose, you can use use the magic method [`__call`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    return call_user_func_array(
        array($this->decoratedInstance, $method),
        $args
    );
}
```

You can also add `__callStatic`, `__get` and `__set` as needed. But note that the magic interceptors always incur some performance penalty. If you have a lot of nested decorators, this might be noticable. When in doubt, benchmark.

Comment: Hey Gordon, yes you're right, it's the ones I'm not modifying that it'd be nice to avoid writing. Thanks. I've tried something along those lines, the problem is that since the decorator is a subclass of whatever class you're decorating, the method being called already exists (i.e. it exists in the parent class) so __call() isn't getting executed.

Comment: @owise1 That's a weird [decorator](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) then. But anyway, if the class is a subclass, I dont see the problem? Just use your IDE of choice and override what you need to override. Everything else can stay as it is since it will be called from the parent class then.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think you've helped me see the error in my ways.  The decorator doesn't necessarily have to be a subclass of the main class.  I was under the impression that's just how you did it, for type checking reasons (the decorated object still "looks like" the original object).  But programming to an interface is perfect , so I can use __call().

Comment: btw, the subclassing was causing problems. When the original object holding all the correct instance variables was decorated, and a method was called that was not overridden and therefore passed to the parent class, that parent class did not have the instance vars it needed to return the right value.  But no matter, that's just because I was doing it wrong to begin with, thanks @Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

The GOF recommends that all of the classes in this pattern derive from a single abstract component class. You could derive a class from an existing class to add this functionality in a DynamicComponent clasto the same effect. You derive inner objects from this class. This class is where magic methods can be used to dynamically handle properties and route messages. You would need __get(), _*set(),*_call() and perhaps__construct(). I use a factory method with protected constructors to simulate multiple inheritance. The factory returns a stand alone component or a wrapped component(usually as directed by a collection builder like a tree builder which gets it's data from a database for example).

The wrapping functionality happens in an abstract class also derived from the common component class.

You provide implementations of each method in the common interface. These overriding functions synchronize the data in the inner item and the outer item and provide the wiring to pass unhandled messages through to the inner item. In effect, every class involved in this pattern automatically receives basic __get() and __set() functions from the parent and extended ones from the inner_item. These are linked in the abstract class to send messages to their inner_item counterparts. 
The concrete wrapper gets the component interface for free from it's parent and can focus on the added functionality. If you wanted to get rid of the common parent, then the common interface would need to be re-implemented in every concrete wrapper class. Another benefit is the ability to add functions like compare and __toString() to the base class. The objects can be used completely interchangeably in functions like usort() and other list/tree/stack/cue/array/whatever structures because they don't just look like the same interface, they are the same type!